# Spring Boot Raw WebSocket Set Principal

Tags: java, spring, websocket, spring-websocket

I want to develop notification sender in real time with Spring Boot but I can't use Stomp and sockjs, so I need implement raw WebSocket but I can't find out how to set Principal in WebSocket connection beacuse I want to Authenticate with JWT token. So, where or how can I set principal.
I'am using these;

WebSocketConfig.java :

```
@EnableWebSocket
@Configuration
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

  @Autowired
  WebSocketNotificationSenderService senderService;

  @Override
  public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry
                                              webSocketHandlerRegistry) {

     webSocketHandlerRegistry.addHandler(createHandler(),
            "/handler").addInterceptors(new HttpSessionHandshakeInterceptor()
     {
        @Override
        public void afterHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request,
                                   ServerHttpResponse response, WebSocketHandler wsHandler,
                                   @Nullable Exception ex) {

            super.afterHandshake(request, response, wsHandler, ex);

        }

        @Override
        public boolean beforeHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request,
                                       ServerHttpResponse response, WebSocketHandler wsHandler,
                                       Map<String, Object> attributes) throws Exception {

            return super.beforeHandshake(request, response,
                    wsHandler, attributes)
        }

    });
}

@Bean
public WebSocketHandler createHandler() {

    return new MyHandler(senderService);

}
}
```

MyHandler.java :

```
@Component
public class MyHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {

WebSocketNotificationSenderService senderService;

public MyHandler(WebSocketNotificationSenderService senderService){
    this.senderService = senderService;
}

@Override
public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
    senderService.addToSession(session);
}
}
```

WebSocketNotificationSenderService.java :

```
@Service
public class WebSocketNotificationSenderService implements 
IWebSocketSenderService<WrapperWsNotification> {

private List<WebSocketSession> sessions = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

public void addToSession(WebSocketSession session) {
    sessions.add(session);
}

@Override
public void convertAndSend(WrapperWsNotification payload) throws JsonProcessingException {
    String payloadString = mapper.writeValueAsString(payload);
    sessions.stream().forEach(session -> {
        try {
            session.sendMessage(new TextMessage(payloadString));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    });
}

@Override
public void convertAndSendToUser(String user, WrapperWsNotification payload) throws 
  JsonProcessingException {
    String payloadString = mapper.writeValueAsString(payload);
    sessions.forEach(session -> {
        if (session.getPrincipal().getName().equals(user)) {
            try {
                session.sendMessage(new TextMessage(payloadString));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

My Notification Sender to websocket;

```
@Component
public class NotificationConsumer {

@Autowired
WebSocketNotificationSenderService webSocket;

private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NotificationConsumer.class);

public void onReceiveNotification(String object) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    WrapperWsNotification wrapperWsNotification= objectMapper.readValue(object, WrapperWsNotification.class);
    logger.info("User where coming from redis " + wrapperWsNotification.getUser().getUsername());
    webSocket.convertAndSendToUser(wrapperWsNotification.getUser().getUsername(), wrapperWsNotification);
}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find out solution and added an [example](https://github.com/zblash/SpringRawWebSocketSecurity)